# Safe to consume pork basting liquid directly?

Tags: food-safety, pork, grilling

I've been watching Sam the Cooking Guy a lot lately, and I was excited to see that his newest video featured my favorite sandwich, the Cuban.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gj5kgvnzxDo

(skip to 2:30 in the video)

I trust Sam's skills, however I was a bit taken aback when he brushed some of the basting liquid directly onto the bread, using (apparently) the same container and brush that had been used on the pork during grilling.

Granted, he only brushed it on the meat after that side had been grilled.

Is this safe?  If so, why?

Comment: Btw at 2:30 there's no brushing bread happening, he just brushes the meat.

Comment: Seeing him brush the bread would be useless without knowing how the liquid was used prior to that, and 2:30 is where the meat brushing starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I was able to tell exactly what he did when watching the video.  What I know is that you should not use a marinade that came into contact with raw meat as a brushed on finishing sauce.  Once it has come into contact with raw meat, it is not safe to consume uncooked.  It is possible that he marinated the meat in a portion of the marinade, and reserved a smaller portion (no contact with raw meat) to use as a finishing sauce.

Comment: He did wait to brush each side of the meat until after that side had been grilled, so I suppose you could say that the liquid _didn't_ touch raw meat.  But seeing it still surprised me.

Comment: @JohnGordon it depends on whether or not the raw meat was in the marinade before he used it as a finishing sauce.

Comment: The meat wasn't in the sauce prior to cooking.  I suppose I shouldn't have called it a marinade.  I edited the question.